# Multiple compilers, still can't use PlaySound

Tags: c, windows

just got Programming Windows 5th ed. by Charles Petzold (kind of old but good; pub. 1998 for Windows 98) and a simple program in Chapter 3 uses PlaySound. Chief error message is:
undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'

I've tried compiling and running the program with NetBeans and the MinGW Developer Studio, with Cygwin and MinGW respectively. I would've tried CodeBlocks and MSVS but cannot use them on my machine. I've tried linking winmm.lib and also including mmsystem.h
(which shouldn't be necessary as windows.h references it).

PlaySound is called in the callback function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 HDC         hdc ;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
 RECT        rect ;

 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_CREATE:
      PlaySound (TEXT ("hellowin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC) ;
      return 0 ;
```

How do I get PlaySound to work?

Comment: It is a linker error so focus on what you link.  For mingw you need link libwinmm.a

Comment: With the help of:http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/61038/ I was able to use this. In MinGW Dev Studio I went to project->Settings->link tab, and entered "winmm" in the library text box. This produced the desired result and now the program works.

Comment: Mingw always seems to require reading at least 10 google hits :(

Comment: I would be using Cygwin, except that it and Windows are not Bestest Buddiez.

Comment: It is kind of like the Apple strategy, they make sure that iTunes on Windows really sucks.